# How to import multiple XML files into one inDesign document without copy/paste?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I use InDesign CS6, and I have several XML files with the same structure. Only the data are
different.
I created  an Indesign layout with some tagged placeholder frames on merge mode, for automated layout.
Today for each XML file I have to create a new InDesign document to import
the XML. Everything works fine. Then in order to have all Indesign
layouts one after the other into a single Indesign layout, I have
to use the copy/paste function.
I mean for example, copy the contents of all documents to the first one. Or add pages of other documents to the first one, then delete spaces between each page.

So my question is the following:
How to repeat this process without copy/paste function, knowing that the
number of XML files could be unknown.

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: There are probably better ways to go about it, but the InDesign javascript api supports copying and pasting with `app.copy()` and `app.paste()`.

Comment: Thank you. I resolved the problem by InDesign scripts. Scripts are powerful for development.

Comment: If this question is solved, please leave a solution for others by answering your own question.