# How to import multiple XML files into one inDesign document without copy/paste

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have several XML files with the same structure. Only the data are different.
I created  an Indesign layout with automatic mappings between XML tags and InDesign cells.
Today for each XML file I have to create a new InDesign document to import the XML data. Everything works fine. Then in order to have all Indesign layouts setting  one after the other into one single Indesign layout I have to use the copy/paste function.
 I mean for example, in page 1 of my Indesign document I need to have the XML content of the first import. In page 2 of my Indesign document I need to have the XML content of the second import, etc....Each Indesign page having the same layout but with different data.

My question is the following:
How to repeat this process automatically knowing that the number of XML files could be unknown

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import multiple XML files into one inDesign document without copy/paste?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369280/how-to-import-multiple-xml-files-into-one-indesign-document-without-copy-paste)